# JPA/Hibernate entity found after rollback, entitymanager clear and cache evict

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jta

I have this test method:

```
public void myMethod()
{

    transactionManager.begin();
    entityManager.joinTransaction();
    MyEntity e = MyEntity();

    entityManager.persist(e);
    entityManager.flush();

    Assert.assertNotNull(e);
    Assert.assertNotNull(e.getId());

    Long id = e.getId();

    entityManager.detach(e);

    Assert.assertFalse(entityManager.contains(e));
    Assert.assertFalse(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().
        contains(MyEntity.class, id));

    e = null;

    entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
    transactionManager.rollback();
    entityManager.clear();

    e = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, id);

    Assert.assertNull(e);
}
```

In the related DB there isn't any MyEntity (database is created each time I run the test), because there isn't an explicit commit the DB remain clean after the execution of the method but the last Assert (the one after the last find) still continues to fail because the previous persisted (but rolled-back) instance is found.

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit transaction-type="JTA" name="persistenceUnit">

    <jar-file>myjar.jar</jar-file>  

    <properties>
        <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:persistenceUnitDB"/>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:persistenceUnitDB/persistenceUnitDB"/>-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I cannot understand why this code has this behaviour.

Comment: What database are you using. It just might not supports transactions. So you can't roll it back

Comment: I tried with both oracle and hypersonic

Comment: Maybe autocommit is on in your settings of transaction manager

Comment: Should it work, right?

Comment: You can add your config settings to your post. Maybe there are some isues. Also if you can you can try to run your test on MySql db and use innoDb engine for table

Comment: @birya i've added my persistence.xml